# combining and minifying files with r.js in a folder without resolving requirejs calls. rjs.options.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, bundling-and-minification, r.js

I'm trying to create `org.combined.js` (`org.combined.min.js`) files from all scripts inside `<Project>/org` folder WITHOUT DEPENDENCIES with R.JS, compiler should not try to resolve requirejs calls *JUST FOR NOW (I might wanna enable this later, now it's conditional dependencies, which baffle rjs)*.

I'm struggling to get working

### rjs.option.js file

File structure:

```
<Project>
         /node_modules/.bin/r.js + r.js.cmd
         /node_modules/requirejs/...
         /build/rjs.options.js
         /build/buildScript.cmd
         /dist/ >>> where all output should be generated to
         /scripts/ <some system level scripts, loaders, which should not be affected>
         /scripts/org/ <some framework scripts, which need to be combined and minified and put into dist/scripts
```

To make an accent on what is required to be done: scripts inside folder "org" should be minified:

```
<Project>/scripts/not-to-be-combined1.js
..
<Project>/scripts/not-to-be-combinedN.js

<Project>/scripts/org
<Project>/scripts/org/to-be-combined1.js
...
<Project>/scripts/org/to-be-combinedN.js
```

Switch findNestedDependencies in rjs.options.js set to false. Config rjs.options.js:

```
{
    appDir: '../',
    baseUrl : './scripts/',
    mainConfigFile : 'org.loader.config.js',   
    //out: 'dist/org.combined.js',
    //dir: 'dist/scripts',
    findNestedDependencies: false,
}
```

Documentation of r.js is very bad and complex, every option depends on other options and usage is not transparent to me at all. I get combined file sometimes, but it's not getting minified.

I'm using NodejsTools for Visual Studio, so WebEssentials doesn't work / help here. Optimally would be a solution utilizing npm, is there a visualizer of options, some helper for context menu, or it's only command line?

I've seen into the alternatives, like [node-minify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-minify), but I'm locking myself out for futher *smart* requirejs directive-aware compilation, so it must be done with rjs. Thanks.

Other try:

```
{
    baseUrl: '../scripts/',
    mainConfigFile: '../scripts/org.loader.config.js',
    dir: '../dist', //scripts,
    findNestedDependencies: false,
    modules: [        
        {
            //module names are relative to baseUrl
            name: '/dist/org.framework',
            //List common dependencies here. Only need to list
            //top level dependencies, "include" will find
            //nested dependencies.
            include: [                    
                'org/org.core',
                ...
                'org/org.dialogs'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you check out the latest webpack? I guess it's much simpler and faster.